# How to retrieve image from database and set as background image using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am working on Server on side code and using jsp and servlet .I am developing one login and registration page where I have to add customer details and related photo of them. I have written code for uploading an image to the mysql database but I am sticking in retrieving an image and how I can make that image as their profile picture.

Please Help.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: are you saving image as blob in mysql?

Comment: Hi Ashish What is Your actual problem?Retriving or making it as profile picture.

Comment: please post code which you have tried so far

Comment: Retrieving is my problem.